# What is \0 (a number prefixed with a backslash) in Perl?

Tags: perl

I saw a piece of code in Perl as below:

```
my $SUCCESS = \0;
my $FAILURE = \1;
```

It is an assignment and I cannot understand the significance of \1 and \0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\1` creates a reference to a scalar. Print `$SUCCESS` and you'll see `SCALAR(0xb83938)` or something similar. In order to get the value try printing `$$SUCCESS` and you should get the value of the variable.

Comment: and same with \0 ?

Comment: Yes.  Try `perl -e 'my $zero = \0; print $zero . "\n"; print $$zero . "\n";'` from the command line to see what they're printing and play around with different values for `$zero`.

Comment: understood but what is the use of using such statements .Is there any programming benefit , Why not just use simple 0 and 1 for success and failure?

Comment: I think some JSON modules produce `false` and `true` for `\0` and `\1`. They couldn't use numbers or strings because that would prevent people from generating JSON that included those numbers or strings.

Answer (score 5):

These two specific values are [special cases](http://p3rl.org/JSON#other-references) in the JSON family of modules, and serialise to `false` and `true`.